# Perform full Merge between the columns of two data frames, based on starting alphabet

Tags: python, pandas

I want to perform full merge between the values of two columns (Name) of two different data frames. Merge should only be done between Names starting with same alphabet. For eg. ABC should be merged with all Names of other data frame which start with letter 'A'. And this should be done for all letters 'A' to 'Z'. I am writing the following code. But length of full merge shows 0. I also want to append the result obtained after merging based on each letter into a new data frame. What changes should I make? Here's my code -

```
for c in ascii_uppercase:
    df1 = df1[df1.Name.str[0] == c ].copy()
    df2 = df2[df2.Name.str[0] == c].copy()
    df1['Join'] =1
    df2['Join'] =1
    FullMerge = pd.merge(df2,df1, left_on='Join',right_on='Join')
    len(FullMerge)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a column of 'FirstLetter' and `[merge][1]` on that.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(ascii_uppercase), (5, 3)))
df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([''.join(x)], index=['Name']), axis=1)
df1['FirstLetter'] = df1.Name.str.get(0)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(list(ascii_uppercase), (1000, 10)))
df2 = df2.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([''.join(x)], index=['Name']), axis=1)
df2['FirstLetter'] = df2.Name.str.get(0)

df1.merge(df2, on='FirstLetter')
```

All you should have to do with your dataframes is:

```
df1['FirstLetter'] = df1.Name.str.get(0)
df2['FirstLetter'] = df2.Name.str.get(0)
df1.merge(df2, on='FirstLetter')
```

columns with common names will be have a suffix appended (which you can control: [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)).  All columns should be represented.  Caveat, you may need to use the `how` parameter to change the merge behavior to one of either `'inner'` (default), `'outer'`, `'left'`, `'right'`.

`df1`

[image]

`df2.head()`

[image]

`df1.merge(df2, on='FirstLetter').head()`

[image]

Comment: What does (5,3) and (1000,10) indicate?

Comment: That was what I used to generate random data.  `(5, 3)` says grab 5 rows and 3 columns of random letters.  I subsequently join them.  Same thing with `(1000, 10)`.  You don't need those dataframes.  I just used them to demonstrate.

Comment: Thats an amazing Solution. I have two doubts - 1. How do I perform this on actual names in my data? 2. Also, I want to keep other columns intact from both data frames in my result.

Comment: Do you have any idea to modify this solution int he case when the Names are too high in number? Kernel seems to die while running this code. It takes forever to get the result of full merge. This is why I was trying to do it letter by letter. Any Suggestions? Your support will be highly appreciated.